# DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version selenium Grid

Tags: selenium

I Have A problem with selenium grid The Node my (pc) Register To The hub (google cloud ubuntu 16.04) But In console grid panel I See This Msg

"DefaultRemoteProxy unknown version,Connect to ip:4444 [/192.168.1.3] failed: connect timed out"
and in ssh of the server 
"Marking the node ip:4444 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries"
but before this message " Registered a node ip:8143"
I Try To change The Port But not work for me

Any Help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Selenium grid. They are working on fixing it.

Comment: About a year later - I just installed 3.14 on a PC and a Mac, first install ever, and am seeing this message. The node on the Mac registers but trying to run a test fails with the titled message. Is there a workaround?  I see a thread stating downgrade to 3.09 is one solution. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5934